# How to invoke an event tied to the UI

Tags: c#, wpf

How to invoke an event tied to the UI from `c#` backend code

```
private void Pumpkin_Leave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
```

Comment: It should be MouseEventArgs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simulate the event, if you don't really use the parameters received, just use this:

```
Pumpkin_Leave(null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks! that took the error away using the first set of code I posted. Now my wpf form calls the event when I press the button, using Pumpkin_Leave(null, null);